# Makefile `go version` and the `read` command

Tags: go, makefile

I want to extract and verify go version in Makefile.

This works in shell:

```
% go version | read _ _ version _ && echo "A $version Z"
A go1.21.1 Z
```

But doesn't work in Makefile

```
check-golang-version:
    go version | read _ _ version _ && echo "A $$version Z"
```

The result:

```
% make check-golang-version
go version | read _ _ version _ && echo "A $version Z"
A  Z
```

Ultimately I wanted to have check like this:

```
check-golang-version:
    go version | read _ _ version _ && test "$$version" = "go1.21.1" || $(error "wrong go version: $$version")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `make` uses `/bin/sh` as the shell (see [5.3.2 Choosing the Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html)).

And it's very likely that when you execute the command in a shell, the shell is `zsh`. The `zsh` pipeline behaviors differently from most of the other shells. See https://riptutorial.com/zsh/example/19869/pipes-and-subshells for an example.

I would recommend to use `go env GOVERSION` to get the version of go and assign it to a Makefile variable:

```
version = $(shell go env GOVERSION)

check-golang-version:
ifneq ($(version), go1.21.1)
    $(error wrong go version: $(version))
endif
```

Comment: I appreciate explanation on zsh, and for the better solution. Thank you!